# User cannot be found. error only on some folders inside a site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, 2016

I am the admin of SP2016. I have created folders inside my site. When I access sharepoint via browser, I'm able to enumerate through all the flders/files. 
I'm trying to write a program via CSOM. Via code, I'm not able to access some of the folders, I get the following exception.

> 2019-04-10 12:24:07.548   36 ERROR User cannot be found.
>   2019-04-10 12:24:07.548    8 ERROR Get:: Exception thrown Message(User cannot be found.) StackTrace(   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Any idea why ?

EDIT: Adding code

```
            if (type == "folder")
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder = webClientContext.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            clientContext.Load(folder.Folders);
            clientContext.Load(folder.Files,
                files => files.Include(file => file.Name)));
            item = folder;
        }
        else if (type == "file")
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = webClientContext.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
            clientContext.Load(file);
            item = file;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Comment: You need to share you CSOM code. Are you using document sets in this library by any chance?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've updated the code.

Comment: What about second part of my question. Are you using document sets?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that. No, we are not using any Document sets. Thanks!